# Modify database files

Tags: mysql

I have a system that a client designed and the table was originally not supposed to get larger than 10 gigs (maybe 10 million rows) over a few years. Well, they've imported a lot more information than they were thinking and within a month, the table is now up to 208 gigs (900 million rows).

I have very little experience with MySQL and a lot more experience with Microsoft SQL. Is there anything in MySQL that would allow the client to have the database span multiple files so the queries that are run wouldn't have to use the entire table and index? There is a field on the table that could easily be split on, but I wasn't sure how to do this.

The main issue I'm trying to solve is a retrieval query from this table. Inserts aren't a big deal at all since it's all done by a back-end service. I have a test system where the table is about 2 gigs (6 million rows) and my query takes less than a second. When this same query is run on the production system, it takes 20 seconds. I have feeling that the query is doing well, it's just the size of the table that's causing the issue. There is an index on this table created specifically for this query, and using an EXPLAIN, it is using it.

If you have any other suggestions/questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: have a look at MySQL Partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) and especially the part of create table that sets the data_directory and index_directory.

With these options you can put partitions on separate drives if needed. Usially though, it's enough to partition with a key that you can use on each query, usually time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to partitioning which has been mentioned you might also want to run the [tuning-primer](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/tuning-primer.sh) script to ensure your mysql configuration is optimal.